# Restrict Wildfly HTTP requests

Tags: wildfly8

Using wildfly 11 on Linux. How can I configure standalone.xml to ONLY respond HTTP requests to specific ip addresses and subnets?

I have tried using interfaces but I figured out that is only for the server interface.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="10.43.4.31"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="10.43.4.31"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```